# split string by certain character in c program

Tags: arrays, c, string, split

I have a string "Hello;World" and I am trying to use a c program to split this string into the components Hello and World basically spliting the string at the ;.

Below is the code I am for trying to accomplish this:

```
int main() {
    char* buffer = "Hello;World";
    char store_hello[10], store_world[10];
    int total_read;

    total_read = sscanf(buffer, "%s;%s" , store_hello, store_world);

    printf("Value in first variable: %s",store_hello);
    printf("\nValue in second variable:  %s",store_world);
    return 0;
}
```

I should be able to set an output of:

```
 Value in first variable: Hello
 Value in second variable: World
```

but I am not getting this output.  How do I tweak the program to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%[^;]` specifier instead of `%s` specifier to have `sscanf()` scan until the next semicolon.

```
    total_read = sscanf(buffer, "%[^;];%s" , store_hello, store_world);
```

Also don't forget to remove an extra space.

```
    printf("\nValue in second variable: %s",store_world);
```

Comment: suppose I have a string "Hello;Word;World".  How do I separate each of these components using sscanf?

Comment: `const char* str = "Hello;Word;World"; char c[3][128]; sscanf(str, "%[^;]%[^;];%s", c[0], c[1], c[2]);`

Comment: One more question in regards to this topic.  Suppose I have a string "Hello;World:Hello World Now".   What do I do if I wanted to separate this string by the semicolon so that I have the strings "Hello","World", and "Hello World Now"?

Comment: `sscanf(str, "%[^;]%[^:]:%s", c[0], c[1], c[2]);`

Comment: I meant to say the string is "Hello;World;Hello World Now".  I am trying to split this string into "Hello", "World", "Hello World Now".  Unfortunately, I am only getting the strings "Hello","World","Hello".  In the last string how do I ensure that I get all the words even though they are separated by spaces and not just the first word?

Comment: Ah, I missed that point. Then use `%[^;]` also for the last token: `sscanf(str, "%[^;]%[^;];%[^;]", c[0], c[1], c[2]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231181/discussion-between-jms1980-and-mikecat).